# How to redirect all HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, ssl-certificate

The website in question has been indexed by google on it's `https://` URL. But recently the SSL Certificate subscription ended.

Now when people click on the link in Google the browsers `unsafe privacy page` is displayed, because we lack a SSL certificate.

How to redirect ALL requests to the http site?

We tried this, but it didn't work:

## https redirect

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Why not renew the certificate and redirect **http** to **https**, to provide them with a secure browsing experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't redirect https to http if you don't have a valid https certificate.

(More precisely, you can, but with the scary red browser warning)

You can create a new certificate with let's encrypt for example. (must be renewed every 3 months, but it's free and can be automated)

Answer (score -1):

By default the server should not redirect to https. This means that you have a redirection rules in the `.htaccess` file or your web application is hard coded to be accessible only via https.

Comment out or remove the lines you point at and the redirect should be removed.